# Getting error message while installing Android Studio

Tags: android

I am getting the following error message when I try to install Android Studio on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I used the pauolo rotolo repository method to install.

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/android-studio_5.2.1-ubuntu0_all.deb (--unpack):
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 8
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/android-studio_5.2.1-ubuntu0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me fix it, since I tried every method to install without glitches, but in vain.

Comment: "I used the pauolo rotolo repository method to install" -- I recommend using [the official Linux bundle](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#linux-bundle). If not, contact the creator of `android-studio_5.2.1-ubuntu0_all.deb` for assistance, as it is rather unlikely that anyone else is going to know what this random `.deb` contains or what that particular error message means.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am now installing from the official website. Also, I could not extract the contents of .zip file into the /opt folder. Kept getting an access denied error message. Even used Nautilus, but to no effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is to learn how to use your operating system. You need root permissions to extract files to /opt

Answer (score 0):

Download android studio ide from official website: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads then install openjdk and other required dependecies. Extract and run Android Studio and let it to download sdk tools for you.

You can follow this tutorial: https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu

But install openjdk 8, not Oracle Java

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it but somehow, the studio.sh file keeps disappearing from the bin folder. I even created a desktop entry/shortcut and it disappeared from the Launcher a day later. I'm installing it again now after removing all the previous files from my system. I'll update the status in a while.